# Random selector

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++17

**Overview:**

The object of the type `random_selector` acts as a function object and randomly choose one element from the specified sequence. Length of the sequence is inferred automatically. Also some convenience member functions are provided. It is meant to be a part of my benchmark v2 framework.

**Code:**

```
#ifndef AREA51_RANDOM_SELECTOR_HPP
#define AREA51_RANDOM_SELECTOR_HPP

#include "random_int_generator.hpp"
#include "utilities.hpp"

#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T,
        typename RandomNumberGenerator = shino::random_int_generator<std::size_t>>
class random_selector
{
    std::vector<T> pool;
    RandomNumberGenerator rng;
public:
    using value_type = std::add_const_t<T>;
    using reference = value_type&;
    using iterator = typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator;

    template <typename InputIt>
    random_selector(InputIt first, InputIt last):
            pool(first, last),
            rng(0, pool.size() - 1)
    {
        if (pool.size() == 0)
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Range cannot be empty");
        }
    }

    random_selector(std::initializer_list<T> init_list):
            pool(init_list),
            rng(0, init_list.size() - 1)
    {
        if (pool.size() == 0)
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Range cannot be empty");
        }
    }

    //let T and RandomNumberGenerator decide on rule of 5

    reference operator()()
    {
        return pool[rng()];
    }

    template <typename OutputIt>
    void operator()(OutputIt first, OutputIt last)
    {
        while (first != last)
        {
            *first++ = pool[rng()];
        }
    }

    //sfinae friendly reset
    //Q stands for Qualified
    template <typename QRandomNumberGenerator,
            typename = shino::enable_sfinae<QRandomNumberGenerator,
                    RandomNumberGenerator>>
    void reset_generator(QRandomNumberGenerator&& next_rng)
    {
        rng = next_rng;
    }

    std::size_t data_size()
    {
        return pool.size();
    }

    iterator begin()
    {
        return pool.cbegin();
    }

    iterator end()
    {
        return pool.cend();
    }
};

#endif //AREA51_RANDOM_SELECTOR_HPP
```

**Demo:**

```
#include "../src/random_selector.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    random_selector<std::string> selector({"Marzhan", "David", "Jack", "Aisulu", "Darkhan", "Akbota"});

    for (const auto& name: selector)
    {
        std::cout << name << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n"
              "Choosing 10 random names from pool:\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        const std::string& current_name = selector();
        std::cout << current_name << ", ";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> Marzhan, David, Jack, Aisulu, Darkhan, Akbota,
>
> Choosing 10 random names from pool:
>
> Darkhan, Marzhan, Jack, Darkhan, David, Darkhan, Jack, David, Marzhan, Aisulu,

**Requirements:**

on type `T`:

- Whatever `std::vector<T>` requires

on type `RandomNumberGenerator`:

- Have constructor that accepts pair of numbers, \$a\$ and \$b\$ that tells the object to generate numbers only in range \$[a;b]\$.
- `operator()` that outputs data implicitly convertible to `std::size_t`. Range **must** correspond to \$[a;b]\$ in the constructor call.
- Destructible

Functions:

- Empty input range on constructor call is prohibited. If the implementation will be able to detect it, the constructor will throw `std::invalid_argument` or its derivative. It is safe to assume that `std::distance()` will be mimicked. (This will give me some breathing room in implementation details).

**Design decisions:**

- Weird RNG: I usually use a wrapper over the generator and distribution, so I don't care about it. May be in the future I'll have different distribution object, so I want to have both tightly coupled.
- Immutable elements: I can't come up with any case when modifying elements wouldn't be an error. May be a pool of random generators could, but that sounds weird at best.
- SFINAE on reset generator: first reason is obvious. Second: I remember there was a problem with universal references, but I've long since forgotten what the problem was. It just turned into a habit.
- Few constructors: implementing other ones would impose more complex requirements on `T`, so I decided to delegate to `std::vector<T>`.

**Critique request:**

Feel free to comment on anything. My major concern is leaving rule of 5 to `T` and `RandomNumberGenerator`, but I couldn't implement SFINAE friendly move constructor, so left it as it is.

**Necessary stuff to run the demo:**

The following code is not intended to be part of the review post, but if you have any thoughts feel free to comment on those as well:

**random_int_generator.hpp:**

```
#ifndef RANDOM_ENGINE_HPP
#define RANDOM_ENGINE_HPP

#include <random>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_integer_type = std::is_integral_v<T>;

namespace shino {
    template<typename IntegerType = int, typename RandomNumberEngine = std::mt19937_64>
    class random_int_generator {
        std::unique_ptr<RandomNumberEngine> engine;
        std::uniform_int_distribution<IntegerType> dist;
    public:
        template <typename ... Ts>
        random_int_generator(IntegerType first = 0,
                             IntegerType last = std::numeric_limits<IntegerType>::max(),
                             Ts&& ... args):
                engine(std::make_unique<RandomNumberEngine>(std::forward<Ts>(args)...)),
                dist(first, last)
        {}

        //allow move construction since it is disabled by deleted copy constructor
        random_int_generator(random_int_generator&& other) = default;

        void range(IntegerType first,
                   IntegerType last = std::numeric_limits<IntegerType>::max())
        {
            dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<IntegerType>(first, last);
        }

        std::pair<IntegerType, IntegerType>
        range()
        {
            return {dist.a(), dist.b()};
        };

        template<typename OutputIt>
        void operator()(OutputIt first, OutputIt last)
        {
            while (first != last) {
                *first++ = dist(*engine);
            }
        }

        IntegerType operator()() {
            return dist(*engine);
        }

        /*
         * Providing const versions doesn't make sense because
         * it is impossible to do anything meaningful with
         * const random int generator
         * */
        RandomNumberEngine& get_engine()
        {
            return *engine;
        }

        std::uniform_int_distribution<IntegerType>&
        get_distribution()
        {
            return dist;
        }
    };
}

#endif
```

**excerpt from utilities.hpp:**

```
template <typename QualifiedType, typename OriginalType>
using enable_sfinae = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<QualifiedType>, OriginalType>>;
```

Comment: Just a small note: You seem to use using things from the `shino` namespace. We have no access to that namespace and its contents, so we cannot execute the code or use some specific things from it. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @Rakete1111, yeah, sorry. It is part of my Area51 repo, and it is a mess. I'm ashamed to put links to it here, so I don't :) I'll put the code required to run it into the post.

Comment: @Rakete1111, done. I believe it will also clarify the first design decision. It still won't run out of the box, but adding some namespaces and includes should make it work.

Comment: Thanks! Inline variables are only a thing since C++17, not C++14. Maybe change the relevant tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some general comments:

1. `random_selector` doesn't have a virtual destructor, which probably means you don't need/want someone to inherit from it. It that it the case, mark it as `final` (if not, provide a virtual destructor):

   ```
   // ...
   class random_selector final
   // ...
   ```
2. You don't seem to use to modify `pool`. Why not mark it as `const`?
3. Mark functions that don't throw `noexcept`.
4. Some functions (like `data_size`, `begin`, `end`, ...) have no reason not to be called when the selector is `const`. Mark them as `const`:

   ```
   const random_selector rs;

   // std::size_t data_size();
   rs.data_size(); // illegal

   // std::size_t data_size() const noexcept
   rs.data_size(); // legal (noexcept because it doesn't throw)
   ```
5. Leverage the fact that [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) provides `begin` and `end` functions to implement a constructor in terms of another (which is good practice - avoids duplication):

   ```
   random_selector(std::initializer_list<T> init_list) :
          random_selector(init_list.begin(), init_list.end()) {}
   ```
6. I would have used [`std::generate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) instead of that hand rolled loop:

   ```
   std::generate(first, last, [&rng, &pool]() {
       return pool[rng()];
   });
   ```
7. Use `std::vector::empty` instead of `std::vector::size() == 0`.
8. Instead of constructing the generator with the range as arguments, I would pass the range when calling the generator. I would also pass the range as a constructor argument. This has 2 advantages:

   - You can nicely pass a lambda:

     ```
     random_selector selector{ { 1, 2, 3 }, [](int min, int max) { return 42; } };
     ```
   - You can pass a function, instead of a function object.
9. You're naming is a bit misleading: `reference` is a `const&` and `iterator` is `const`. Consider changing them to `const_reference` and `const_iterator` respectively.

Comment: I think that instead of passing a lambda one can pass disguised `*this`.

Answer (score 3):

`static_assert()` and `<type_traits>`could document at least some of your requirements, resulting in clearer compile-time messages.

C++17 seems to feature `std::sample`. Just mentioning.

Lately I am sick of Constilness, so this might be biased. More `const`! For example `const std::vector<T> pool;`.